# PHP - Run function after while loop ends

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, while-loop

This may not be the best solution to my problem, but I'm interested to know anyway.

Is it possible to defer a function or piece of code till after a while loop ends? I assumed this happened anyway if it was placed below, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

What I'm trying to accomplish is inside the while loop some session data is being saved (if it does not exist, which is the condition). When the loop finally ends, since the session data is set, the code below which relies on the session data can be executed.

This is in a CodeIgniter 3.0 system, so it is using the session driver:

```
// Uses a helper function session_isset (see below) to check if the session data is set, and if at least one of the supplied data variables is null then try to set it

while(!session_isset(array('instance_id','instance_prefix'))) {
    $this->session->set_userdata('instance_id', $instance->instance_id);
    $this->session->set_userdata('instance_prefix', $instance->instance_prefix);
}

// The get_managers() function, which ultimately calls a model function, relies on the set session data to get a table prefix which is prepended to all relevant database queries
// This should ideally only be allowed to run once the session data has been confirmed as set

if($manager = $this->manager->get_managers(array($manager_id))[0]) {
    $manager->instance_id = $instance->instance_id;
    $manager->instance_prefix = $instance->instance_prefix;
    echo json_encode($manager);
}

function session_isset($data) {
    $ci =& get_instance();
    foreach ($data as $value) {
        if(is_null($ci->session->userdata($value))) return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

So just to reiterate, is there a way to defer code until a while loop has ended, similar to a callback?

Also, is there perhaps a better way to ensure session data is set before running functions that depend on it?

Comment: "Is it possible to defer a function or piece of code till after a while loop ends? I assumed this happened anyway if it was placed below, but that doesn't seem to be the case." it most certainly IS the case

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm just not understanding how the session data process works, because the whole thing always works on the second attempt, after the session data has been stored, but it just won't work immediately after telling it to save.